# insertAtPos method DoublyLinkedList

Tags: java

I want to try to add a string at a certain position in a node. For some reason, when I try to enter a new string at a position, it erases all the existing data that was already on the list. I am not sure what is wrong.

```
public void insertAt(String data, int pos)
    {
        if(head == null)
            insertAtStart(data);
        else if(pos < 1 || pos > size)
            System.out.println("Position Out Of Bounds");

        Node current = head;
        int i = 1;
        while(i < pos)
        {
            current = current.next;
            i++;
        }

        if(current.prev == null)
        {
            Node newLink = new Node(data);
            current.prev = newLink;
            head = newLink;
        }
        else
        {
            Node newLink = new Node(data);
            current.prev.next = newLink;
            current.prev = newLink;
        }
        size++;
    }
```

Comment: It's common practice to start the `pos` at 0, not 1. I recommend that you do the same.

Comment: In my project, we have to start at 1, that is why I didn't start at 0

Comment: In the "out of bounds" case, you probably want to return instead of continuing adding to an invalid index.
If you care about single return point (good practice IMO), you can move the part after the `println` into an `else` body.

Comment: Thank You for the suggestion, I moved everything after println into an else body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take the following points under consideration

1. current node is currently the first element in the list?
2. current node has ended up somewhere in the middle of the list?
3. current node is currently the last element in the list?

And Each of this case has it's unique handling

For Case 1

```
        if( current == head ) // sure its the head but..
        {
            if( head.next != null ) // is the list NOT EMPTY?
            {
                newLink.next = head;
                head = newLink;
            }
            else // list is empty
            {
                head = newLink;
            }
        }
```

For Case 2, current is somewhere in the middle

```
 current.prev.next = newLink;
 newLink.prev = current.prev.next;

 newLink.next = current;
 current.prev = newLink;
```

// the previous pointer of current points to the newLink

// Since it's a doubly list, newLink.prev pointer POINTS BACK to the node previous to current

// Whats next to the newLink? current Right?

// Since it's a doubly list, current.prev pointer POINTS BACK to the newLink

For Case 3, current is null, end of list, but remember if saved the pointer before the current in the for loop, we could fix this problem too

```
prevToCurrent.next = newLink;
newLink.prev = prevToCurrent;
```

Now lets compile all the cases

```
public void insertAt( String data, int pos )
{
    if( head == null )
    {
        head = new Node( data );
    }
    else
    {
        Node newLink = new Node(data);
        Node current = head , prevToCurrent = null;
        for( int x = 1; current != null && x < pos; x++ )
        {
            prevToCurrent = current;
            current = current.next;
        }
        if( current == head )
        {
            if( head.next != null )
            {
                newLink.next = head;
                head = newLink;
            }
            else
            {
                head = newLink;
            }
        }
        else if( current == null )
        {
            prevToCurrent.next = newLink;
            newLink.prev = prevToCurrent;
        }
        else
        {
            current.prev.next = newLink;
            newLink.prev = current.prev.next;

            newLink.next = current;
            current.prev = newLink;
        }
    }
    size++;
}
```

Let me know if something goes wrong as I tested and compiled it before posting it as an answer for you

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting `newLink.prev` and `newLink.next`. This result in a broken link in the middle of the linked list.

In the head case (`current.prev == null`), before overwriting `head`:

```
newLink.next = head;
```

In the common case, before overwriting `current.prev`;

```
newLink.prev = current.prev;
newLink.next = current;
```

Comment: When I try to insert a data at the end of the list with this method, it gives me null pointer exception saying that there is something wrong with in the head case (current.prev == null)

Comment: If you have a list of 5 elements, and you start at 1, you have to add at 6 to add to the end, correct? That means that your `while` loop will bring you to the last element's `next`, which is `null`. That should be what's throwing the `NullPointerException`.
I recommend adding a special case for `pos == (size + 1)`, which also means you have to change the "out of bounds" condition.

Comment: So for the out of bounds condition, I just have to add size + 1 (pos > size + 1). Then create a new case for pos == (size + 1), if the pos is at the end, insert it at the end

Comment: Correct. However, to simplify the design, I would recommend adding _after_ `current` instead of _before_. That way, your `head` case will be the only special case, and all you need to do is walk one less node in your `while` loop.

Comment: Thank You I'll see what I can do